# Is it possible to export IOS framework from IOS projects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, storyboard

I'm working on IOS Project (swift code + UI), now i want to export a private framework from my code, like `.aar` files in android.
How can i do it?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Google "Create framework ios Swift"

Comment: I know how to create framework but now I have project and i want to convert it to IOS framework

Comment: Add a `Cocoa Framework` target in you project and attach all relevant files to this target. Thats all can be suggested without knowing more details of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot convert. But can create a new project and choose Framework as the target and create as many files you want to be included in that Framework and then export it.

Comment: is it possible to have pods in that newly created framework? then how to export whole framework with required pods?